# Finding research problem for PhD(TCS)?

Tags: co.combinatorics

I am a theoratical computer science PhD student.

I am wanted some suggestion in how to find research problem for PhD research. I have supervisor and he has given me first problem. We had get progress in this. Now I have to do things fully by my self. Going conferences and workshop is not possible because of money problem.

In order to finding research problem what I do

```
I open scholar.google site then I search different keywords from my area (which is word combinatorics)
If some thing look relevant then I read conclusion section
If I haven't understand then I go for introduction and abstract part
If I find ok then I read paper else left
```

Solving these kind of problems looks difficult. Earlier I had searched some problems and I had tried but I haven't get results as per in sending some conference. So I had left those problems. That is why I am wanted some input in this regards.

Comment: I think this might be more suitable for [academia.se]. I vaguely remember we had a question similar to yours about how to choose a problem to work on for thesis.

Comment: Does word combinatorics include automata?  Take a look: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22493/are-there-any-open-problems-left-about-dfas/22563#22563

Comment: Also, some conferences have travel funds.  If you have a reason to attend and a recommendation from your adviser, then you can apply and hope to get most of your travel covered.

Comment: If you would like to talk more, please let me know.  Have a nice day.  :)

Comment: here is a [similar question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/42679/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-a-professor-who-is-not-your-supervisor-to-give-you-m-s) from [academia.se] on a MS thesis topic. as stated it is generally frowned on by cyber denizens and academics to get thesis topics anywhere other than from an advisor. however, minority/ contrarian view, think this goes against grain of [open science](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/65426/open-science). fyi heres list of many [near-open science](https://vzn1.wordpress.com/chat/) prjs by se users discussed/ announced in chat(s).

Comment: ps also try [chat] and note that, in line with MWs idea, related work in any of the [leading/ famous open problems](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/174/major-unsolved-problems-in-theoretical-computer-science) is always an excellent research "bet"....

Answer (score 4):

Read [Feynman's letter](http://scienceblogs.com/thescian/2008/03/11/what-are-worthwhile-problems-f/). Very good advice.

Always be curious and solve little problems you are good at. Eventually you will have enough solved for a major publication.