# Deciding whether $2^k+m$ is prime

Tags: ds.algorithms, pspace

I thought something fancy can be done with number-theory or memoization, but neither worked for me. Being limited in knowledge I decided to ask experts.

*Does there exist a deterministic polynomial-space algorithm
for the following decision problem?*

> **Instance:** Two positive integers $k$ and $m$ in decimal representation.
> **Question:** Is $2^k+m$ a prime number?

Some comments:

- By polynomial-space I mean that the space complexity of the algorithm should be bounded by a polynomial in the input length $\log k+\log m$.
- The naive approach to this problem determines the decimal representation of $2^k+m$ and then applies a fast primality testing algorithm.
  It is easy to see that this naive approach requires exponential space,
  just for writing down the decimal representation of $2^k+m$.
- This is related to another [question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3563818/602057).

Comment: (i) By "polynomial space" do you mean polynomial in the size of the (presumably binary) encoding of $K$ and $M$?  That is, polynomial in $\log K + \log M$?  (ii) _"Calculating $k\mapsto 2^k$ takes exponential time"_ is a strange thing to say.  Do you just mean _representing $2^k$ takes space exponential in $\log k$_?  That's sort of obvious, I think, so doesn't help clarify your post or why it is interesting (my opinion).  And the post you link to, and its answers, reflect a similar confusion.  But I think the question you ask is interesting.  Editing the post to clarify it would help.

Comment: The notation seems to be switching randomly. Is $k=K$ and $m=M$?

Comment: Anyway, as far as I am aware, no such algorithm is known even in the special case of Fermat primes ($M=1$, $K$ a power of $2$).

Comment: @EmilJeřábek An idea: Can we show its in $NP$, because $PSPACE$ = $NPSPACE$? That would non-constructively prove that an algorithm exists.

Comment: All problems in $NP$ are in $PSPACE$, just by showing its in $NP$ is enough to prove a deterministic poly-space algorithm exists. Whether one is known is apparently open.

Comment: A positive answer here would in particular falsify the more general “no formula for primes” conjecture here: https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/46902/formalizing-the-no-formula-for-primes-intuition, and least given a modest extra assumption.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving I found out how to generate all possible expressions of $2^k$+$m$ given that I use a solution as input. (eg. solution = 5, output expression $2^0$ + $4$ = $5$, $2^1$ + $ 3$ = $5$)  I am fairly new to ComputerScience, but wouldn't that mean a "turing machine" can recognize the "language" in polytime?

Comment: @Travis: The hard part, of course, is recognizing which are prime.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving We have AKS primality, which is poly-time. All the solutions are prime numbers and can be recognized in poly-time. After the primality, we then find the expressions. Although, probabilistic tests are more practical.

Comment: @GeoffreyIrving Not hard at all.https://pastebin.com/qCcfnSRG

Comment: Of course you can it in polynomial time in the number of bits of the prime, but this is too slow to resolve either of our questions.

Comment: you may want to look at this post.  
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3810222/primality-test-for-specific-class-of-n-k-cdot-2n1